# Using Yii Active Record to find max of one column

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii, max

How can I find max value of one column in database by Yii Active Record?

I can do it by pure sql and `createCommand` method,but I wanna do it by Active Record and `CDbCriteria` class.is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will want to change the select criteria as follows.

```
$model = new Model;
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select='max(column) AS maxColumn';
$row = $model->model()->find($criteria);
$somevariable = $row['maxColumn'];
```

Reference:

[http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/6730-how-can-i-use-max-in-find-method/page_*view*_findpost_*p*_80659](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/6730-how-can-i-use-max-in-find-method/page__view__findpost__p__80659)

Answer (score 6):

This avoids creating an unnecessary temporary object:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = 'max(column)';
// additional where conditions, if you so wish
$criteria->addColumnCondition(array('published' => 1));
$model = SomeModel::model();
$value = $model->commandBuilder->createFindCommand(
    $model->tableName(), $criteria)->queryScalar();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just limit the result and order by DESC e.g

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->order = 'column DESC';
$row = Model::model()->find($criteria);
$somevariable = $row->column;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a WHERE clause:

In controller:

```
$max = $model->getMax($filter);
```

In model:

```
public $maxColumn = 0;
public function getMax($filter = null)
{
    /* Get max in column1 WHERE column2 = $filter */
    $criteria               = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select       = 'MAX(t.column1) as maxColumn';
    $criteria->condition    = 't.column2 LIKE :parm';
    $criteria->params       = array(':parm'=>$filter);

    $tempmodel  = $this->find($criteria);
    $max        = $tempmodel['maxColumn'];
    return $max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$model = MyModel::model();

$maxId = $model->getCommandBuilder()
        ->createSqlCommand('SELECT MAX(id) FROM '.$model->tableName())
        ->queryScalar();

$maxId = Yii::app()->db
        ->createCommand('SELECT MAX(id) FROM '.$model->tableName())
        ->queryScalar();
```

Answer (score -1):

This is it.

```
function getMaxId( $modelName ){
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->order = 'id DESC';
    $model = $modelName::model()->find( $criteria );
    return $model->id;
}
```

Comment: This isn't flexible enough.
If I had a table of users, with their age, weight, and height stored and wanted to select the top 10 tallest people and get the maximum weight for that subset, I couldn't extend your answer to get the results I wanted at all.